# Word for something about a product making someone not want to buy the product, which they had wanted to buy

Tags: word-usage

"They wanted to buy that thing but the design... them and they decided to buy another brand"

I have thought about "scare off", "put off", "sway off", but they don't seem right.

Comment: I would use 'put off'.

Comment: Why doesn't 'put off' seem right?

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Because if you just insert it you get "...design put off them..." whereas we would normally say "...design _put_ them _off_"?

Comment: @decapitatedsoul because I don't want to put emphasis on their emotional response to seeing the thing they don't like, but rather on the physical fact of them not taking this product. So, I thought about the word "sway" whihh means "to move off course" and add "away" or "off" to indicate the direction. But neither sway away or sway off aren't used in that meaning, that is what Google told me.

Comment: I don't see how you clearly distinguish an emotional and physical response. For instance, *repel* has a physical sense to it (being pushed away), but that denotes an emotional response of revulsion or distaste as well.

Answer (score 4):

How about "dissuade"? The OED defines this verb as "deflect (a person) by persuasion or influence (from (an action etc., doing))."

Comment: Welcome to [English.SE]! This is a valid answer, but it would be even better if you provided a definition from a reliable source.  I would encourage you to edit your answer to include that information as well.

Comment: Thanks, thats a good suggestion. How about the following sentence: "We need not to try any crazy designs in order not to ... any potential customers."? I dont like dissuade here, but in my question's example i like it.

Comment: I would suggest that you use "scare away" here. OED defines it as follows: "to make someone so worried about doing something that they decide not to do it."